# How to append elements in an array to another array?

Tags: immutability, ramda.js

How to append elements in an array to another array using Ramdajs with a single line statement?

```
state = {
   items:[10,11,]
 };

newItems = [1,2,3,4];

state = {
  ...state,
  taggable_friends: R.append(action.payload, state.taggable_friends)
}; 

//now state is [10,11,[1,2,3,4]], but I want [10,11,1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ramda's `append` works by "pushing" the 1st param into a clone of the 2nd param, which should be an array:

```
R.append('tests', ['write', 'more']); //=> ['write', 'more', 'tests']
R.append(['tests'], ['write', 'more']); //=> ['write', 'more', ['tests']]
```

In your case:

```
R.append([1,2,3,4], [10,11]); // => [10,11,[1,2,3,4]]
```

Instead use RamdaJS's [`concat`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#concat), and reverse the order of the parameters:

```
R.concat(state.taggable_friends, action.payload)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use just basic JavaScript you can do this:

```
return {
  ...state,
  taggable_friends: [...state.taggable_friends, action.payload],
}
```